# Internet switching

Tags: esp8266, gsm

is it possible to switch internet connection from esp8266 wifi module to gsm sim 900A internet if the arduino detects that the esp have no internet connection and vise versa? Thanks

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thank you!, can you guide me how to do it? I'm stuck in this situation, please

Comment: What did you try and what happened? Show your code please!

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @TimeGold, your question asks a simple yes/no confirmation ... if you actually need help with your code, then you need to rewrite your question